# C# Azure get specific directory with files

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to get a specific folder from azure. The name looks like 528646646-2020-02-01TGDZ.25.738.
But I want to find the folder only with the first numbers (528646646). And when I have this one, I want get all the files contains in this folder.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is the folder named `528646646`? Also, what version of Azure Storage SDK you're using?

Comment: No, the Folder is named 528646646-2020-02-01TGDZ.25.738, I use the newest. It installed it automatically with Visual Studio.

Comment: Any process now?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, cause you say you are using the newest sdk so I suppose you are using the Azure Blob storage client library v12 for .NET.

If yes, you could use [GetBlobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getblobs?view=azure-dotnet) method to implement it. This method allows prefix  to filter  the results.

You could refer to my below code.

```
string connectionString = "storage connection string";

            // Create a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("container1");

            Pageable<BlobItem> blobs = containerClient.GetBlobs(prefix: "images");

            foreach (var blob in blobs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(blob.Name);
            }
```

I list all file with `image` prefix.

[image]

Suppose this is what you want, hope this could help you.